# How to write rtf on ubuntu?

Tags: files, c++

I have a program to read and write rtf, doc, docx, pdf,... file. So, do you know the lib or program to process these files, especially rtf.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) reads these files. See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice#Supported_formats).